# $ROS_ROOT/rosconfig.cmake fot catkin?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the equivalent of $ROS_ROOT/rosconfig.cmake fot catkin?
I want to set some build flags for all my catkin packages.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82816/$ros_root/rosconfig.cmake-fot-catkin?/) by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you considered using a CMake toolchain file (http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#The_toolchain_file)?

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1